# Can't install HTML_QuickForm2

Tags: php, pear, ubuntu-14.04

I have been trying to install HTML_QuickForm2. I ran the command `sudo pear install HTML_QuickForm2`. Unfortunately it gives me error that is:

```
WARNING: failed to download pear.php.net/HTML_QuickForm2-, additionally the suggested version () is the same as the locally installed one.
install failed
```

When I checked the `usr/share/php/` and `usr/share/php/PEAR`, I did not see that `HTML_QuickForm2` is installed in this location. So, I retried but am getting same error. Additionally, I have installed `PEAR` recently, is there anything to configure in `php.ini` for `PEAR`?

P.S. I am using the OS Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 too and just installed it using `sudo pear install HTML_QuickForm2-2.0.2`

And it got installed at this location:

```
/usr/share/php/HTML/QuickForm2
```

Comment: I used as your mentioned command but no luck. Getting same issue.

Comment: Well seems like you've already installed it given the error message. Did you try to check out the HTML folder of the install path? And just out of curiosity, why are you using `HTML_QuickForm2`? Nobody uses that anymore. That's some antique stuff.

Comment: I did not see any `HTML` folder into `/usr/share/php/` directory. Thanks for your recommendation. I used in my personal old cms. It's not serous something but it gets headache why it is not installed.

Comment: I have installed it finally, just manually created the `HMTL` folder. However, thanks to comment here.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you